# How to create Python user defined function to read CSV files?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, user-defined-functions

I'd like to create a function that reads each file I want to import as a CSV, and all the files I'd like to read are in the same folder on my desktop. So would this code be correct if I want the input to be the filename (since it's the only thing different each time I want to read a file as CSV)?

```
def readCSV(filename):
    filepath = 'C:\\Drive\\Desktop\\Folder\\ + filename'
    readFile = pd.read_csv(filepath)
    return readFile
```

or would it only work if the code is like this?

```
def readCSV(filename):
    filepath = C:\\Drive\\Desktop\\Folder\\ + filename
    readFile = pd.read_csv('filepath')
    return readFile
```

My main concern with the first function is that the filename is within a string (aka the filepath), so I am not sure if this would work in Python or not.

Comment: It should be `'C:\\Drive\\Desktop\\Folder\\' + filename`

Comment: @SergioPeñafiel for the first or second function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File pathnames should be in proper string format, as in if you use the `print()` function to output the file path, it should be exactly the same as how you want the pathname to appear.

Therefore, your path should be the concatenation of 2 strings, the first one being the absolute path of your C: drive and the second being your file name.

```py
"C:\\Drive\\Desktop\\Folder\\" + filename
```

OR if you want to use string formatting:

```py
f"C:\\Drive\\Desktop\\Folder\\{filename}"
```